# Input Range autofocus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, slider

I have a simple range slider. As you know if I want to change the value of the range slider I can either click anywhere at the range slider or click on the slider thumb and drag it.

I want to change the value of the range slider only by mousemove without actually clicking and dragging if it's possible using JS/jQuery.

Something like autofocus on the range so I can drag the thumb without long pressing..

```js
$('#myRange').mousedown()
```

```css
#myRange {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="myRange">
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with the native element. You could investigate building your own.

Comment: Could you help me with that ?

Comment: There are a number of different approaches and Stack Overflow really isn't a tutorial site. I would suggest Googling for something like "How to create a custom slider in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript".

Comment: I think you lost me. I know how to create a customized slider, or perhaps you mean a range slider without the input tag

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'll work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="myRange">

$('#myRange').mousemove(function(e){
  var positionOnSlider = 100 * (e.pageX - $('#myRange').offset().left)/$('#myRange').innerWidth()
  
  $('#myRange').val(positionOnSlider)
})
```

[Demo CodePen](https://codepen.io/kslaton/pen/QWGOgaw)